# How do I declare the generic type of an instance dynamically in java

Tags: java, generics

I am mocking an interface that doesn't use generics, but does take a `Class` type as an argument.

```
public Object query(Class c, Filter f)
{....}
```

Is there a way in my implementation to use `c` as the argument for a generic?

eg.

```
return new ArrayList<c>();
```

Obviously I could do a `switch` if I had a know set of values for `c`, but that is a very ugly hack that I don't want to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Care explain why this is community wiki!

Comment: In case anyone feels a burning desire to edit it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a helper method:

```
 private <T> List<T> createList(Class<T> klass) {
          return new ArrayList<T>();
 }
```